# How can I add a new file to my Git repository?

Tags: git, branch, addition

I'm creating some new files and am trying to add them but when I use `git add applications/libraries/calendarclass.php`, it won't recognize that I have a file there

I just created that file in textmate and am staring at it. How do I add it to git?

```
releventz$ git add application/libraries/calendarclass.php
fatal: pathspec 'application/libraries/calendarclass.php' did not match any files
releventz$ ls
application css     index.php   license.txt
authnet     images      js      system
releventz$ cd application
application$ ls
cache       controllers errors      hooks       language    logs            third_party
config      core        helpers     index.html  libraries   models          views
application$ cd libraries
libraries$ ls
MY_Unit_test.php    index.html      loginclass.php
libraries$ git branch
* master
libraries$ git add calendarclass.php
fatal: pathspec 'application/libraries/calendarclass.php' did not match any files
```

When I use `git status`

```
libraries$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: Actually, your `ls` output doesn't show the file there, too. How should git guess what file your want to add there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After adding your new file, type:

```
git status
```

You should then see the file ready to be added - then either type `git add (filename)` or `git add .` if you want to add all of them.

If `touch`ing the file doesn't do the trick, you may need to take a look at your `.gitignore` to make sure there's no funny business going on in there, like an exclude all or anything similar.

Comment: tried that..i pasted the response in my original post. any help is much appreciated

Comment: In that case, I'd try what @NickAldwin suggested which is to "touch" the file. That should _definitely_ do it.

Answer (score 5):

From your output, it looks like `calendarclass.php` doesn't exist.  If you want to create the file, then add it to git, do:

```
touch calendarclass.php
git add calendarclass.php
```

Comment: @David Your `ls` command did not show it.  Either you saved it in the wrong directory or didn't save it at all.

Comment: @David I'd still try to `touch` it - that's a surefire way of knowing it is in the directory.

Comment: Also, the Textmate code that you're seeing could be cached, or like @NickAldwin said, in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your calendarclass.php is not noticed by git because of a rule in a .gitignore file. Remove that rule and you will be able to add the file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove whitespaces from the tail of your filename.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like calendarclass.php does not exist to add it, and it seemed you have not modified your code after last commit that's why there are no unstaged nor staged files, may be you merged from another branch into master locally, that's why it says it is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.

Comment: or maybe the file is ignored by .gitignore